# VS hangs before generating code

Tags: visual-studio

When I build solution, it seems VS hangs before generating code. VS stucks at Creating library xxxx this line. What's wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't add text as graphics.

Comment: Also, you _might_ want to change your username...